# Slow boot after reinstalling GRUB

Tags: release-loki, boot, dual-boot, grub

I recently installed ElementaryOS Loki 0.4.1 in my SSD on top of an old Windows 10 dual-boot with Ubuntu 17.04 setup. Ubuntu was in my HDD, so GRUB detected it and included it in the OSes list after booting. But now I wiped it clean and installed Windows 10 in the HDD, so I had to use `boot-repair` to fix it and followed the standard repair routine. It gave me an error in the end, but the log file wasn't saved to my home for some reason, but the GRUB update worked fine. I can see my elementaryOS and Windows listed correctly on GRUB.

However, my boot time increased a lot (to more than 3 minutes) and I'll include the output of `dmesg` and `systemd-analyze plot`.

`dmesg` is too long to include here, so I chopped some stuff off, but the problems I noticed are related to the Bluetooth apparently, maybe the following lines:

```
[    9.432748] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver in 8 mode, major device number 243
[   98.575621] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
```

and:

```
[  105.638811] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp5s0: link becomes ready
[  189.179729] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
```

The almost complete output:

```
[    1.046472] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20160711 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    1.092688] [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train [i915]] *ERROR* failed to train DP, aborting
[    1.094919] random: fast init done
[    1.142546] [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train [i915]] *ERROR* failed to train DP, aborting
[    1.144642] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    1.144699] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[    1.144719] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[    1.186754] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.206746] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.322311] ata5: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    1.322328] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    1.323676] ata5.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[    1.323678] ata5.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[    1.323679] ata5.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[    1.324265] ata1.00: ATA-8: KINGSTON RBU-SNS8100S3128GD, S8FM06.9, max UDMA/133
[    1.324267] ata1.00: 250069680 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    1.324926] ata5.00: ATA-8: HGST HTS721010A9E630, JB0OA3J0, max UDMA/133
[    1.324928] ata5.00: 1953525168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    1.324949] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    1.325213] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      KINGSTON RBU-SNS 06.9 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.326188] ata5.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[    1.326190] ata5.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[    1.326192] ata5.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[    1.327366] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    1.335477] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8008
[    1.335479] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.335816] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.335898] hub 1-1:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    1.354900] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 250069680 512-byte logical blocks: (128 GB/119 GiB)
[    1.354932] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    1.354933] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.354940] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.354942] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    1.355158] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000
[    1.355160] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.355299] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      HGST HTS721010A9 A3J0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.355425] hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.355519] hub 2-1:1.0: 8 ports detected
[    1.356437]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3
[    1.356666] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.398938] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[    1.398941] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    1.398963] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    1.398964] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    1.398966] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.398973] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.622756] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    1.628409] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x361f03)
[    1.642751] usb 2-1.8: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    1.646066] psmouse serio1: elantech: Synaptics capabilities query result 0x00, 0x15, 0x0e.
[    1.663878] psmouse serio1: elantech: Elan sample query result 05, 6b, 64
[    1.733042] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=07dc
[    1.733043] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.751020] input: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
[    1.753982] usb 2-1.8: New USB device found, idVendor=1770, idProduct=ff00
[    1.753984] usb 2-1.8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=1, SerialNumber=1
[    1.753985] usb 2-1.8: Product: MSI EPF USB
[    1.753986] usb 2-1.8: Manufacturer: MSI EPF USB
[    1.753986] usb 2-1.8: SerialNumber: MSI EPF USB
[    1.756735] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.759304] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.759304] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.830721] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2494.224 MHz
[    1.830727] clocksource: tsc: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x23f3e9a353a, max_idle_ns: 440795330815 ns
[    2.608950]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
[    2.609486] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[    2.854758] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    2.931211] [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train [i915]] *ERROR* failed to train DP, aborting
[    8.166944] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    8.280010] systemd[1]: systemd 229 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN)
[    8.280167] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[    8.280340] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <vamcs-elementary>.
[    8.343417] systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
[    8.343463] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
[    8.343491] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    8.343517] systemd[1]: Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    8.343543] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    8.343562] systemd[1]: Listening on LVM2 poll daemon socket.
[    8.343637] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[    8.399891] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    8.402834] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[    8.456952] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    8.463293] systemd-journald[380]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    8.652341] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
[    8.654404] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    8.656172] EDAC ie31200: No ECC support
[    8.686998] RAPL PMU: API unit is 2^-32 Joules, 4 fixed counters, 655360 ms ovfl timer
[    8.687000] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp0-core 2^-14 Joules
[    8.687000] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain package 2^-14 Joules
[    8.687001] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain dram 2^-14 Joules
[    8.687002] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp1-gpu 2^-14 Joules
[    8.688962] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[    8.688963] Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation
[    8.689032] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.704215] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    8.704217] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[    8.711536] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.711688] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    8.711721] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.712555] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.459231.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    8.712903] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    8.712914] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    8.712914] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.712917] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.712919] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.712923] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.718863] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    8.728850] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0: autoconfig for ALC892: line_outs=2 (0x15/0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    8.728853] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    8.728854] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    8.728855] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    8.728856] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    dig-out=0x1e/0x0
[    8.728857] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
[    8.728859] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Mic=0x18
[    8.728860] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[    8.733642] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370710018002030d55
[    8.733644] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel device is already patched. patch num: 55
[    8.737289] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input8
[    8.737352] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input9
[    8.745167] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input10
[    8.745226] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input11
[    8.745283] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input12
[    8.752021] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[    8.752023] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[    8.752026] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    8.752028] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
[    8.752032] intel_rapl: RAPL package 0 domain package locked by BIOS
[    8.752045] intel_rapl: RAPL package 0 domain dram locked by BIOS
[    8.755507] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[    8.757563] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    8.757810] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    8.770200] input: MSI WMI hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input13
[    8.781095] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    8.781098] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[    8.781098] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[    8.784160] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    8.832593] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[    8.832775] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 244
[    8.832792] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  375.66  Mon May  1 15:29:16 PDT 2017 (using threaded interrupts)
[    8.841956] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  375.66  Mon May  1 14:33:30 PDT 2017
[    8.842990] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
[    8.844895] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160422/nsarguments-95)
[    8.844942] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160422/nsarguments-95)
[    8.844971] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160422/nsarguments-95)
[    8.844998] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160422/nsarguments-95)
[    8.845025] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160422/nsarguments-95)
[    8.845060] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160422/nsarguments-95)
[    8.845088] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160422/nsarguments-95)
[    8.949516] random: crng init done
[    8.995583] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    8.996844] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0 wlp5s0: renamed from wlan0
[    9.004151] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160422/nsarguments-95)
[    9.038106] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounting ext2 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[    9.040228] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
[    9.128621] audit: type=1400 audit(1498408617.703:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/ippusbxd" pid=800 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.128933] audit: type=1400 audit(1498408617.703:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=798 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.129046] audit: type=1400 audit(1498408617.703:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=801 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.129480] audit: type=1400 audit(1498408617.703:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=796 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.129483] audit: type=1400 audit(1498408617.703:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=796 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.129485] audit: type=1400 audit(1498408617.703:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=796 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.129488] audit: type=1400 audit(1498408617.703:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=796 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.130488] audit: type=1400 audit(1498408617.703:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=795 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.130493] audit: type=1400 audit(1498408617.703:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium" pid=795 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.131458] audit: type=1400 audit(1498408617.707:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=799 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.410432] Adding 8306684k swap on /dev/mapper/elementary--vg-swap_1.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:8306684k SSFS
[    9.411457] nvidia-modeset: Allocated GPU:0 (GPU-76c185c2-53c5-0650-3131-0f0efd7aa80a) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
[    9.411692] nvidia-modeset: Freed GPU:0 (GPU-76c185c2-53c5-0650-3131-0f0efd7aa80a) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
[    9.411751] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    9.411752] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.
[    9.432748] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver in 8 mode, major device number 243
[   98.575621] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   98.575624] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   98.575632] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   98.588883] bbswitch: version 0.8
[   98.588889] bbswitch: Found integrated VGA device 0000:00:02.0: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0
[   98.588895] bbswitch: Found discrete VGA device 0000:01:00.0: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP
[   98.588908] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160422/nsarguments-95)
[   98.588993] bbswitch: detected an Optimus _DSM function
[   98.589001] bbswitch: Succesfully loaded. Discrete card 0000:01:00.0 is on
[   98.649162] audit_printk_skb: 27 callbacks suppressed
[   98.649163] audit: type=1400 audit(1498408707.223:21): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=1133 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   98.677427] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready
[   98.679532] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   98.679776] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   98.852006] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
[   98.854247] nvidia-modeset: Allocated GPU:0 (GPU-76c185c2-53c5-0650-3131-0f0efd7aa80a) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
[   98.854559] nvidia-modeset: Freed GPU:0 (GPU-76c185c2-53c5-0650-3131-0f0efd7aa80a) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
[   98.863951] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
[   98.878290] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   98.878538] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   98.900381] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready
[   98.904294] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s0: link is not ready
[   98.906132] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s0: link is not ready
[   99.021815] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready
[  105.631127] wlp5s0: authenticate with 1c:5f:2b:fb:8a:32
[  105.633999] wlp5s0: send auth to 1c:5f:2b:fb:8a:32 (try 1/3)
[  105.634555] wlp5s0: authenticated
[  105.636323] wlp5s0: associate with 1c:5f:2b:fb:8a:32 (try 1/3)
[  105.637438] wlp5s0: RX AssocResp from 1c:5f:2b:fb:8a:32 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[  105.638791] wlp5s0: associated
[  105.638811] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp5s0: link becomes ready
[  189.179729] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  189.179735] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  189.179739] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  197.766603] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  197.907975] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1038, idProduct=1364
[  197.907977] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  197.907978] usb 3-2: Product: Kana Gaming Mouse
[  197.907979] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: SteelSeries
[  197.918128] hid-generic 0003:1038:1364.0002: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [SteelSeries Kana Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[  197.918266] input: SteelSeries Kana Gaming Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.1/0003:1038:1364.0003/input/input14
[  197.978586] hid-generic 0003:1038:1364.0003: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [SteelSeries Kana Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input1
```

And I noticed using `systemd-analyse plot` that there is a huge gap as showed below:
[image]

And I also screenshot the detail just before the gap:
[image: Plymouth services are the last ones to show up before the gap.]

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

---

**EDIT**: it's related to corrupt partitions apparently, I'm trying to use testdisk to fix it and will post answer if I succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem! I followed a similar solution found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612600/15-04-very-slow-boot).

So the problem was that when installing Elementary OS, Ubuntu still existed and the installation used the swap partition from the HDD that belonged to Ubuntu. And since it has been deleted, the UUIDs were incorrectly set at `/etc/fstab`, which apparently loads some partitions on boot (correct me if I'm wrong).

By running `cat /etc/fstab` I could see that it said (not everything included):

```
/dev/mapper/elementary--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=9183ee89-60f4-4fe7-bcd4-0c34da15836b none            swap    sw              0       0
```

But my swap isn't at `/dev/sdb5`, that looks like something from the old Ubuntu installation. It is actually here:

```
/dev/mapper/elementary--vg-swap_1
```

By running `sudo blkid` I got the UUID for it:

```
/dev/mapper/elementary--vg-swap_1: UUID="21945fd8-5962-4482-a0d2-abba965c8594" TYPE="swap"
```

So I simply replaced the old one for it, rebooted my computer and the boot time decreased to:

```
Startup finished in 3.746s (firmware) + 3.811s (loader) + 7.321s (kernel) + 1.940s (userspace) = 16.821s
```

Comment: Good stuff, I have installed additional RAM, and decided I'll just delete the SWAP partition. Shame on me, but your solution seems to have worked for me.